# Direct access to DGPS data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gps

I'm heading out to the Arctic Circle (Spitsbergen) I have a Sokkia DGPS and Magnet on a tablet device (connects to the DGPS and logs the data), they connect via blue tooth etc. Can I bring the data straight into QGIS bypassing Magnet?

Comment: You might want to check that your DGPS performs the way you expect at the destination. Considerations would be DGPS correction reception, correction accuracy (reasonable ground station locations) and satellite geometry (GDOP), especially if you don't have good visibility to the south.

Answer (score 1):

If the data logger stores the positions as tabulated file with Longitudes and Latitudes you can visualize that and, I think you can tell QGIS to watch the file for any alterations.

So basically, yes

Comment: I believe you are looking for a NMEA ouput directly from the GNSS sensor to consume in in the QGIS software. This could be an option on the GNSS receiver, but I believe Magnet would still be needed to initially configure the GNSS receiver for DGPS corrections and establish the NMEA output (message types, which port is being utilize to send the data, etc.). You would be best served to contact your local dealer for additional help.